# How to create a conditional trigger to stop cell being updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

### Background

I have a table `Job_Test` that has a column named `Status`. The value of the column can be one of seven values.

### Question

How can I stop a specific value `New` from being changed to `Hold`? It can however be changed to one of the other six values.

### What I have so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    dbo.statusCheck
ON 
    [dbo].job_test

FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

      If (SELECT [status] FROM job_test) LIKE 'New'
      Begin

      ...

      End

END
```

However I'm not sure where to finish it.

Comment: You should try using an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger

Answer (score 0):

there are `INSTEAD OF` triggers that might help you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.statusCheck_InsteadOfUpdate 
ON statusCheck
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE s SET
        s.[status] = i.[status],
        ... other fields to UPDATE ...
    FROM statusCheck s
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.ID = s.ID
    WHERE i.[status] <> 'Hold' AND s.[Status] <> 'New'
END
```

you can also throw errors if any were found

Comment: Could I raise an error if the query doesn't change the status. I'm struggling to think of a way. At the moment it either changes it to the inserted value or changes it the original value, so there is no error to raise right?